# Выполнение/завершение по датам

Tags: java, планировщик-задач, quartz

Использую cron и quartz. Нужно реализовать следующие: Администратор назначает на конкретную дату некое задание, которое обновляет базу данных. После того как оно выполнится через 24 часа, должно выполнится задание которое обновляет базу данных новыми значениями. После чего удаляет оба задания из планировщика. У меня есть код которые работает каждые сутки. Но я не могу понять как его адаптировать к нужным мне целям. Заранее спасибо

```
public class NewJobDateBorn {

    private static JobDetail job;
    private static Trigger trigger;
    private static Scheduler sched;

    public void creatNewJob() throws SchedulerException {
        job = JobBuilder
                .newJob(DateBornJob.class)
                .withIdentity("DateBornJob", "dateborn")
                .build();

        trigger = TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("DateBornTrigger", "dateborn")
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder
                        .cronSchedule("0 1 0 1/1 * ? *"))
                .build();


        SchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        sched = schedFact.getScheduler();
        sched.start();
        sched.scheduleJob(job,trigger);
    }

    public void removeJob() throws SchedulerException {
        sched.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: к программе *cron* вопрос не имеет ни малейшего отношения.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin А как тогда реализовать то что мне необходимо?)

Comment: берёте редактор и пишете нужный вам код.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, спасибо, отличный ответ) Сам бы я не догадался